# Can Foxit Reader play embedded videos?

Tags: pdf-reader, foxit-reader

I have an interview for which I need to bring a USB key with a PDF presentation and I'm told there will be a "windows 10 Pro PC running Foxit PhantomPDF" (*). I'd like to have show an embedded video during this interview.

Being a linux user, I have no desire to install Foxit and try it out, [the Ububtu-Fr page mentions it is "invasive" (a kind word for spyware?) and doesn't deinstall properly.](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/foxit_reader)

So I'd like to know what chances are that embedded videos will be played by more or less versions of Foxit software. It seems that [Foxit PDF Editor can *add* such media since at least 2021](https://www.foxit.com/blog/how-to-add-an-audio-video-into-pdf-files/), was this a new feature then?

(*) I'm surprised since PhantomPDF appears not to be the name of a Foxit software since 2021, but I wouldn't be surprised if this organisation uses outdated software.

Answer (score 2):

Foxit Phantom PDF isn't Foxit Reader, it's a PDF editor. Foxit renamed it to simply [**Foxit PDF Editor**](https://www.foxit.com/pdf-editor/), but Microsoft Store [still uses the old name](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/foxit-phantompdf/9ND1JWBGZMQF?hl=us-en&gl=se&rtc=1).

According to the [Foxit PhantomPDF User Manual](http://cdn01.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/manual/phantom/en_us/FoxitPhantomPDF9.6_Manual.pdf) it *"not only supports playing videos and audios in PDFs, but also allows users to
add and edit multimedia files to a PDF."*

Any gotchas should be in the manual as well.

Comment: Thanks. The manual specifies that "If an alert message tells you that no media handler is available, you must install the appropriate player before you can add clips to the PDF." So I guess I just have to hope that the proper media player will be present. Quite likely, videos handled by Windows Media Player should be rendered? But then, they say QuickTime is needed for MOV, whereas WMP can play MOV...??

Comment: @JoceNoToPutinsWarInUkraine Yeah, good questions :-) I'd simply contact the potential employer and ask for advice. They know their system's capabilities.

Comment: Well, knowing the organisation, unfortunately I doubt I can get in touch with a person with technical ability. I guess I'll prepare two versions, one of them doing without videos, and add a video with the same codec on the front page so I'll see right from the start which file should be played.

Comment: Ah, one of those :-D Well, that's probably the best plan then. [This MS support page]( https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/file-formats-supported-by-the-movies-tv-app-in-windows-10-b271ca1d-0d26-d0bd-a139-70bf10f19a1b) details Win10 video format support.